# How does one identify the designers of a LEGO set?

Tags: design, set-database

I'm looking for tips to identify the Lego Designers that have worked on a given particular released recent set.
Ideally, I would like to find an online resource that has this information for as much sets as possible, but I'll also consider other options as answers.

Comment: Are you looking for an universal answer that can be applied to any LEGO set, or would you accept answers that would only work for some particular subset of all released sets?

Comment: @Zovits, I'll expand the question to make clear that I consider any information useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One resource I know of that can be considered both correct and up to date is the [LEGO set designers' BrickLists](https://brickset.com/bricklists/featured).

In a few other cases (mostly for larger releases, like in the Ideas line) one might find an interview with the original submitter and the designer who finalized the product for release:

[image]

Comment: And of course exactly the set and designer I was looking for ;)